# Траблы с AWS, ошибка Network Unavailable

Tags: c#, unity3d, amazon-web-services, amazon, amazon-s3

В общем, суть в том, что при отправке запросов любого типа к серверу S3, получаю такую ошибку:

```
Get Error:: System.Net.WebException: Network Unavailable
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.UnityRequest.GetResponse () [0x00044] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\_unity\UnityWebRequestFactory.cs:181 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1[TRequestContent].InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0006d] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\HttpHandler.cs:85 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:57 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00000] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Unmarshaller.cs:48 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:57 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0001f] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:81 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:57 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00007] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:45 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:57 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00006] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Signer.cs:38 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:57 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00007] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CredentialsRetriever.cs:72 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:57 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00040] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RetryHandler\RetryHandler.cs:84 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:57 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00007] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:45 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:57 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointResolver.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00007] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\EndpointResolver.cs:34 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:57 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Marshaller.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00006] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Marshaller.cs:37 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:57 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00007] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:45 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:57 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00012] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\ErrorCallbackHandler.cs:44 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:57 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0002b] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\MetricsHandler.cs:40 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:57 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00006] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RuntimePipeline.cs:135 
  at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke[TRequest,TResponse] (TRequest request, Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.IMarshaller`2[T,R] marshaller, Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.ResponseUnmarshaller unmarshaller) [0x0006b] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AmazonServiceClient.cs:205 
  at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.GetId (Amazon.CognitoIdentity.Model.GetIdRequest request) [0x0000c] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\CognitoIdentity\Generated\_unity\AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.cs:669 
  at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials.RefreshIdentity () [0x00034] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\CognitoIdentity\Custom\CognitoAWSCredentials.cs:350 
  at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials.GetIdentityId (Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials+RefreshIdentityOptions options) [0x00018] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\CognitoIdentity\Custom\CognitoAWSCredentials.cs:321 
  at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials.GetPoolCredentials () [0x00000] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\CognitoIdentity\Custom\CognitoAWSCredentials.cs:693 
  at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials.GenerateNewCredentials () [0x00031] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\CognitoIdentity\Custom\CognitoAWSCredentials.cs:681 
  at Amazon.Runtime.RefreshingAWSCredentials.GetCredentials () [0x00015] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Credentials\RefreshingAWSCredentials.cs:90 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.PreInvoke (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0002a] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CredentialsRetriever.cs:56 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00000] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CredentialsRetriever.cs:112 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:78 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:78 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0000c] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:77 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:78 
  at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3KmsHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0000c] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Custom\Internal\AmazonS3KmsHandler.cs:67 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:78 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointResolver.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0000c] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\EndpointResolver.cs:64 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:78 
  at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3HttpDeleteHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0000c] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Custom\Internal\_unity\AmazonS3HttpDeleteHandler.cs:54 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:78 
  at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3PostMarshallHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0000c] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Custom\Internal\AmazonS3PostMarshallHandler.cs:84 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:78 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Marshaller.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0000b] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Marshaller.cs:67 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:78 
  at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3PreMarshallHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0000c] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\S3\Custom\Internal\AmazonS3PreMarshallHandler.cs:73 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:78 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0000c] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:77 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:78 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:78 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:78 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x0002b] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\MetricsHandler.cs:109 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeAsync (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00008] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:78 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ThreadPoolExecutionHandler.InvokeAsyncHelper (Amazon.Runtime.IAsyncExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00000] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\_unity\ThreadPoolExecutionHandler.cs:56 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.ThreadPoolThrottler`1[T].Callback (System.Object state) [0x00007] in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util\_unity\ThreadPoolThrottler.cs:101 
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
AWSSDK.Examples.AppManager:<ListBuckets>b__11_0(ListBucketsResponse, String) (at Assets/!5@25@/Examples/AppManager.cs:67)
AWSSDK.Examples.<>c__DisplayClass23_0:<ListBuckets>b__0(AmazonServiceResult`2) (at Assets/!5@25@/Examples/S3Manager.cs:114)
Amazon.S3.<>c__DisplayClass102_0:<ListBucketsAsync>b__0(AmazonWebServiceRequest, AmazonWebServiceResponse, Exception, AsyncOptions) (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Services/S3/Generated/_unity/AmazonS3Client.cs:2194)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.UnityMainThreadDispatcher:ProcessRequests() (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/_unity/UnityMainThreadDispatcher.cs:82)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.UnityMainThreadDispatcher:Update() (at E:/JenkinsWorkspaces/v3-trebuchet-release/AWSDotNetPublic/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Ru
```

<sup>(немного обрезалось)</sup>

При отслеживании трафика видно, что юнька к инету не подключается даже, но при использовании метода `Amazon.Runtime.Internal.UnityRequest` отдельно, юнити спокойно присоединяется к инету. В менеджере данные 100% верные. Антивирус выключал, удалял - ничего не помогало. Проекты пересоздавал, AWS SDK переставлял, юньку переустанавливал, пул новый создавал, в исключение юньку добавлял. Понятия не имею, в чем проблема. Может кто нибудь в курсе?

Comment: Что такое `юнька`? Причем тут s3? Куда и что не подключается?

Comment: юнька это Unity 3d, запросы идут к серверу Amazon, а именно к хранилищу S3

Comment: Права доступа прописаны для хранилища? Туда разрешен анонимный доступ? К хранилищу открыт доступ по http/80 или https/443?

Comment: Запросы попробовали постманом или просто браузером слать?

Comment: Да, и прикол в том, что такая ошибка только на моем пк.

Comment: Если s3 недоступно только для вас, а для всего остального мира доступно, то у вас либо проблемы с настройкой доступа к s3, либо программа на вашей машине. У вас есть другие компьютеры/телефоны в вашей сети? (Подключенные к тому же роутеру, что и вы) с них есть доступ к хранилищу? Проверяли файл hosts у себя? Отключали брандмауэр? У вас нет доступа к ресурсу или ко всему ip адресу? Пинг посылали? Traceroute смотрели?

Comment: Брандмауэр отключен, пинги посылал, в том дело, что юнити даже не пытается отправить запрос, сразу выводит, что интернет недоступен. Проверял трафик в Network Traffic view, при "отправке" запросов, ничего не происходит, а в консоль выводится то, что написано в вопросе.

Comment: `пинги посылал` ну а результат то какой? Причем тут юнити? Вы сказали, что у вас s3 недоступен. Вы сказали, что пробовали постманом и браузером, и все равно недоступен. Если это верно, то юнити тут не при чем.

Comment: Говорю же, юнити не отправляет запрос вообще, как будто ему кто-то блокирует доступ в интернет, но методы WWW и WebRequest работают отлично